# PowerAutomate Flow not behaving as intended for SharePoint List Modifications; Issue may be Trigger formulas

Tags: triggers, infinite-loop, power-automate

I have a flow to send an email when an item is modified with two trigger conditions:

1. "Requestor Action" choice field = "Save & Submit"

@equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Requestor_x0020_Action/Value'],'Save & Submit')

2. "Requestor Action Trigger" text field <> "Requestor Action" field

@not(equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Requestor_x0020_Action/Value'],triggerOutputs()?['body/Requestor_x0020_Action_x0020_Tri']))

(I've checked field names in List Settings. They are correct.)

Last step of the the flow sets the value of "Requestor Action Trigger" field to value of "Requestor Action" field successfully, which should end the trigger condition.

The flow is looping every few mins even after trigger condition is no longer met. I get emails for previously modified items, plus any new item I tested that initially met the trigger condition. It took me a while to get syntax errors removed from trigger formulas.. would appreciate if someone can please review and see if I should fix them. Tried fixing for hours. Please don't dock me for bad question. Let me know what to fix or provide.
[image]

---------Issue fixed ---
There was a space inadvertently introduced in the update action when adding dynamic content ('Requestor Action Value') for 'Requestor Action Trigger' field. Discovered it when getting trigger body info for @Skin. Since 'Requestor Action' never equaled 'Requestor Action Trigger' field, the condition to end the loop was never met.

[image]

Comment: Can you remove the conditions and show us a trigger body that meets the relevant conditions?

Comment: Since new to this, had to look up where to find trigger body info. Saw the glaring issue...it was an extra space being added when updating values. I've updated my post with the image. Thank you for bringing my attention to this troubleshooting essential.

Answer (score 0):

In the last flow action where 'Requestor Action Trigger' field is set to dynamic content 'Requestor Action Value', there was a space accidentally added before dynamic content was placed. I noticed it when inspecting trigger body content per @Skin. (My updated post has images of trigger body content and update action where space was added.

Because of the space, 'Requestor Action' never equaled 'Requestor Action Trigger' field, and the condition to end the loop was never met.

Comment: I hope Microsoft adds some visual markers for leading/lagging spaces around dynamic content. It's especially frustrating for beginners.